# how to display all data and where condtion is that order_no should be distinct

Tags: mysql

Here is my MySQL table view:

```
no c_date     order_no table_no ord_menu customer_bill quantity customer_name captain_name payment_status
 1 2015-11-07        2        2 pohe               554        8 vikas         pravom       Done
 2 2015-12-07        2        2 poli-bhaji         554        2 vikas         pravin       Done
 3 2015-11-20        2        2 sarnosa            554        3 vikas         pravin       Done
 4 2015-12-07        2        2 baatata            554        4 vikas         pravin       Done
 5 2015-12-07        3        5 chicken           3074        3 amol          aksh         Done
 6 2015-12-07        3        5 puri              3074        2 amol          aksh         Done
 J 2015-12-07        3        5 samosa            3074        1 amol          aksh         Done
 8 2015-12-07        3        5 ladu              3074        1 amol          aksh         Done
```

and I need to display all data and where condition is that **`order_no`** should be distinct.

Comment: Unfortunately, order_no is never distinct

Answer (score 1):

**Give this a go:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT order_no FROM table_name;
```